# How to set JAVA_HOME or CATALINA_HOME if I have more than 1 version used for Projects?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have different projects using different version of JDK (5.0, 6.0) and Tomcat(6.0, 7.0), so how should my `JAVA_HOME` and `CATALINA_HOME` be set in environment variables?

Or maybe it is NOT necessary to set `JAVA_HOME` and `CATALINA_HOME` in environment variables if I am running my App by `.War` file?  The `jdk/tomcat` server will be running the version I picked when I packed it (through Eclipse -> preferences...).

Answer (score 15):

Inside the tomcat startup script `/bin/catalina.sh`, the following environmental variables are used:

- `JAVA_HOME` is the path of JDK that used to run the tomcat and web applications
- `CATALINA_HOME` is the path of the tomcat binaries  files
- `CATALINA_BASE` is the path the tomcat configuration files

So , how about this approach? For example :

Install JDK 5.0 to : `/opt/jdk5` 
Install JDK 6.0 to : `/opt/jdk6` 
Install tomcat 6.0 to :`/opt/tomcat6` 
Install tomcat 7.0 to : `/opt/tomcat7`

Each of your web application has their own folder to hold their own tomcat 's configuration. For example :
 `/home/web1` for the web application 1
 `/home/web2` for the web application 2

Inside each of these folders , we need the following sub directories: `conf`, `logs`, `temp`, `webapps`, and `work`.Simply copy these sub directories from the tomcat installation folder (ie. `/opt/tomcat7/`)  .Then put the `.war` to the corresponding `webapps` folders (e.g. `/home/web1/webapps/webappl.war` , `/home/web2/webapps/webapp2.war` ).

Finally , write a script to start the tomcat using different JDK and tomcat for each application . For example , to start web1, your script should look likes:

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk  #eg./opt/jdk6 
CATALINA_HOME=/path/to/tomcat/installation #eg./opt/tomcat7 
CATALINA_BASE=/home/web1/
export JAVA_HOME JAVA_OPTS CATALINA_HOME CATALINA_BASE
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start
```

Reference : 
http://www.mohancheema.net/appserver/setting-tomcat-to-run-mutiple-instances-of-it

Comment: Where to write that script where I configure where CATALINA_HOME is? Inside which folder should that script be? Should it have a specific name?

Answer (score 4):

If you are running it with in Eclipse, you can use the Run Configuration dialog to set any enviornment variables that you need to change. These get automatically set when you execute the specified Run configuration. To use this, Right Click on your project, select Run -> Run Configurations. In that you can select a Run Configuration, and goto the Environment tab, and there you can specify the custom variables you want, and also you can override anything that is set by the O/S.

If you want to do this outside eclipse, and you keep a copy of Tomcat dedicated for each project, edit the startup.sh or startup.bat files depending on your OS and then set the environemnt variables explicitly there.

Ex. For Project 1:, on top of /opt/apache-tomcat6-1/bin/startup.sh file add these lines

export JAVA_HOME='/opt/jdk1'
export JAVA_HOME='/opt/apache-tomcat6-1'

Ex. For Project 2:, on top of /opt/apache-tomcat6-2/bin/startup.sh file add these lines

export JAVA_HOME='/opt/jdk2'
export JAVA_HOME='/opt/apache-tomcat6-2'

If you don't have a dedicated copy of Tomcat, then you can create a shell script / batch file per project which will set the necessary environment variables like this and then invoke the corresponding startup.sh or startup.bat file.

Comment: startup.sh is for UNIX, if I run on Windows should be startup.bat, correct?

Answer (score 2):

These variables are used by the scripts that start Tomcat, and don't matter otherwise. You can set them immediately before running the `startup.sh` script, or you can edit the `catalina.sh` script to set the values in the script itself (this is a good way to do it, since `catalina.sh` is shared by the other scripts), or you can write your own scripts which set the variables and then call the tomcat scripts... There are many possibilities. You just can't set the variables globally.