# how to start the tomcat server in linux?

Tags: linux, tomcat, installation, centos, startup

i tried to install

```
   1.yum install -zxvf apache-tomcat-6.0.47.tar.gz then 
   2.  export TOMCAT_HOME=/home/mpatil/softwares/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
   3. [root@localhost mpatil]# echo $TOMCAT_HOME 
      /home/mpatil/softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
```

while starting tomcat by using this command

```
   4.[root@localhost mpatil]# /startup.sh 
bash: /startup.sh: No such file or directory
```

i don't know why it showing like this.

my file in

```
      5.[root@localhost mpatil]#  find /home -type f -name   apache-tomcat-6.0.37.tar.gz
/home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37.tar.gz
```

what i tried before this is is correct or not? --please tell me
my question is how to start a tomcat server in linux.Please tell me..

Comment: This is not a question for [so]. Try asking on [su]

Comment: thanq for your advice

Comment: look at this [link](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-start), got it from google.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The command you have typed is `/startup.sh`, if you have to start a shell script you have to fire the command as shown below:

```
$ cd /home/mpatil/softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin
$ sh startup.sh 
or 
$ ./startup.sh
```

Please try that, you also have to go to your tomcat's bin-folder (by using the cd-command) to execute this shell script. In your case this is `/home/mpatil/softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin`.

Comment: ya i tried to start and done successfully.now how to add JAVA_HOME and   CATALINA_HOME ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172258/how-to-set-java-home-or-catalina-home-if-i-have-more-than-1-version-used-for-pro you have to set the path and export for JAVA_HOME and CATALAINA_HOME check the link

Comment: MY JDK IN  JAVA_HOME=/home/mpatil/softwares/jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz i tried but nothing should comming

Comment: [root@localhost mpatil]# JAVA_HOME=/home/mpatil/softwares/jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz
[root@localhost mpatil]#

Comment: Try this "A Complete Guide To Tomcat Start-Up" tutorial: http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-start

Answer (score 6):

Use `./catalina.sh start` to start Tomcat. Do `./catalina.sh` to get the usage.

I am using apache-tomcat-6.0.36.

Comment: It is `./catalina.sh`

Comment: ./catalina.sh start worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

if you are a sudo user i mean if you got sudo access:

```
      sudo sh startup.sh
```

otherwise: 
          **sh startup.sh**

But things is that you have to be on the bin directory of your server like

cd /home/nanofaroque/servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin

Answer (score 3):

```
cd apache-tomcat-6.0.43 ====: Go to Tomcat Directory 
sh bin/startup.sh   =====: Start the tomcat on Linux 
sh bin/shutdown.sh   ======:Shut Down the tomcat on Linux
tail -f logs/catelina.out ====: Check the logs
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old question, but this command helped me!

Go to your Tomcat Directory
Just type this command in your terminal:

```
./catalina.sh start
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Tomcat Directory with : `cd/home/user/apache-tomcat6.0`

- `sh bin/startup.sh.>> tail -f logs/catelina.out.>>`

Answer (score 0):

**Go to the appropriate subdirectory of the EDQP Tomcat installation directory. The default directories are:**

On Linux: /opt/server/tomcat/bin

On Windows: c:\server\tomcat\bin

**Run the startup command:**

On Linux: ./startup.sh

On Windows: % startup.bat

**Run the shutdown command:**

On Linux: ./shutdown.sh

On Windows: % shutdown.bat

Answer (score 0):

To run `Apache Tomcat server` in `Linux` following ways can be used. Let me share the difference as well since I see some got confusions with the multiple ways `Apache Tomcat Server` can be started.

The `catalina.sh` is the main control script for `Tomcat`. Following are the multiple ways of running tomcat:

```
./catalina.sh run
```

Passing "run" argument for catalina.sh --> starts the Tomcat in the **foreground** and **displays the running logs in the same console**. when the console terminal is closed it **will terminate the tomcat**.

```
./catalina.sh start
```

Passing "start" argument for catalina.sh --> starts the **Tomcat in the background**. Since in background no issues closing down the terminal. The logs need to be viewed as below: `tail -f $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out`

```
./startup.sh
```

The last way is firing the startup.sh to start your Tomcat server. If you Vi the script you can see it calls **catalina.sh script passing start as the argument**. This will be running in background as well.