# How to start tomcat in linux

Tags: tomcat

I extracted tomcat server in the usr/apache directory.
and set the path $ PATH =CATLINA_HOME in etc/bash.bashrc file.
using this command

## vim ~/bashrc .

To check path is setup or not i trigger this below command

## $PATH=CATLINA_HOME

Its showing blank row as output in console.

Before this, i also tried to start the tomcat using # ./bin startup.sh in tomcat directory 
but its giving error 
-bsh command not found.

Someone kindly help me to show how to start tomcat server in in linux

Thanks in advance.
Sajal

Answer (score 0):

you can try

[Tomcat controller GUI](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/screenshots/tomcat-turnkey-control-panel)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check CATALINA_HOME points to the correct folder where tomcat is installed.

Second, the way to set the path is:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$CATALINA_HOME
```

Here you have a link that can respond your question" [How to set JAVA_HOME or CATALINA_HOME if I have more than 1 version used for Projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172258/how-to-set-java-home-or-catalina-home-if-i-have-more-than-1-version-used-for-pro)

Comment: Can you just tell me, where i need to setup all jdk, tomcat,jre PATH. i setup in bash.bashrc file which is exists in etc/ folder , and now i am trying to run command , in apache directory: $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start
-bash: /usr/apache/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/bin/catalina.sh: Permission denied

Comment: @SajalFouzdar, 1-You surely need to start your service at boot time. Read this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot . 2-Here you have a script to start/stop tomcat during boot time: https://gist.github.com/miglen/5590986 . 3-As for the permission denied, you need to be root or have sudo (read about how to configure your user as sudoer)